# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unable to set cookie (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.102)

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

- Enviroment: windows7 + chrome70.0.3538.102(64bit) + selenium-java(3.141.59) + selenium-chrome-driver(3.141.59) + java

  ```
          //obtain cookies
      WebClient webClient0 = new WebClient();
      webClient0.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
      webClient0.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
      webClient0.setCssEnabled(false);
      webClient0.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
      CookieManager cookieManager = webClient0.getCookieManager();
      HtmlPage login1Page;
      try {
          login1Page = webClient0.getPage("http://10.91.42.124:9999/login1.php");
          HtmlInput username = (HtmlInput) login1Page.getElementById("username");
          HtmlInput passwd = (HtmlInput) login1Page.getElementById("password");
          username.type("admin");
          passwd.type("admin123");
          HtmlButton loginButton = (HtmlButton)login1Page.getElementById("loginb");
          HtmlPage TChtmlPage = loginButton.click();
          cookies = cookieManager.getCookies();
          System.out.println(cookies);
      } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      }           
  try {
          chromeDriverPath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\main\\resources\\chromedriver.exe";
          //set up the path of chrome drive
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath);
          //open chrome client
          chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
          chromeDriver.get("http://10.91.42.134:8360/TC.php");
          for(org.apache.commons.httpclient.Cookie cookie : cookies) {
              chromeCookie = new Cookie(cookie.getName(), cookie.getValue(), 
                      cookie.getDomain(), cookie.getExpiryDate());
              chromeDriver.manage().addCookie(chromeCookie);
          }
  ```
- then generate this Error

  > Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unable to set cookie
  >   (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.102)
  >   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711aa874a),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
  >   Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds

i don't know what's meaning?